# using merge sort for string sorting from text file

Tags: java, string, sorting, mergesort

I am going to write a code for sorting string from text file by mergesort method.

**if (l.get(0) <= r.get(0))**

at this part appearing a redline. I know it is only for primitive, I tried to use compareTo but can't finish it properly.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1MKSY.png)

```
private static ArrayList<String> mergeSort(ArrayList<String> lines) {
        if (lines.size() <= 1) {
            return lines;
        }
        ArrayList<String> left = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> right = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (String x : lines) {
            if (lines.indexOf(x) < (lines.size()) / 2)
                left.add(x);
            else {
                right.add(x);
            }
        }
        left = mergeSort(left);
        right = mergeSort(right);
        return merge(left, right);
    }

    private static ArrayList<String> merge(ArrayList<String> l, ArrayList<String> r) {
        ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
        while (l.size() > 0 && r.size() > 0) {
            if (l.get(0) <= r.get(0)) {
                result.add(l.get(0));
                l.remove(0);
            }
            else {
                result.add(r.get(0));
                r.remove(0);
            }
        }
        while (l.size() > 0) {
            result.add(l.get(0));
            l.remove(0);
        }
        while (r.size() > 0) {
            result.add(r.get(0));
            r.remove(0);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

## String.compareTo()

> The Java String class compareTo() method compares the given string
> with the current string lexicographically. It returns a positive
> number, negative number, or 0. It compares strings on the basis of the
> Unicode value of each character in the strings.
> If the first string is lexicographically greater than the second string, it returns a positive number (difference of character value).
> If the first string is less than the second string lexicographically,
> it returns a negative number, and if the first string is
> lexicographically equal to the second string, it returns 0.

> **Note:**
> if **string1** > **string2**, it returns **positive number**
>
> if **string1** < **string2**, it returns **negative number**
>
> if **string1** == **string2**, it returns **0**

qutoes from [gfg](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-string-compareto-method-with-examples/).

use `compareTo` method of `String` because `java` doesn't support `<` & `>` operators for `strings` comparisions.

```
 while (l.size() > 0 && r.size() > 0) {
            if (l.get(0).compareTo(r.get(0))<=0) {
                result.add(l.get(0));
                l.remove(0);
            }
            else {
                result.add(r.get(0));
                r.remove(0);
            }
        }
```

You are getting `SO` Excepetion because of `indexOf` if suppose list has `{"A", "A", "C", "A"}` then `indexOf("A")` will `return 0` ever time you call it.

```
if (lines.indexOf(x) < (lines.size()) / 2)
                left.add(x);
            else {
                right.add(x);
            }
```

## code

```
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;


public class MergeSort{
        final static PrintStream out = System.out;


        private static ArrayList<String> mergeSort(ArrayList<String> lines) {
                if (lines.size() <= 1) {
                        return lines;
                }
                ArrayList<String> left = new ArrayList<String>(lines.subList(0, lines.size()/2));
                ArrayList<String> right = new ArrayList<String>(lines.subList(lines.size()/2, lines.size()));

                /*for (String x : lines) {
                        if (lines.indexOf(x) < (lines.size()) / 2)
                                left.add(x);
                        else {
                                right.add(x);
                        }
                }*/
                /*for(int i =0 ;i<lines.size()/2;i++)
                        left.add(lines.get(i));
                for(int i = lines.size()/2;i<lines.size();i++)
                        right.add(lines.get(i));*/
                left = mergeSort(left);
                right = mergeSort(right);
                return merge(left, right);
        }

        private static ArrayList<String> merge(ArrayList<String> l, ArrayList<String> r) {
                ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
                while (l.size() > 0 && r.size() > 0) {
                        if (l.get(0).compareTo(r.get(0)) <= 0) {
                                result.add(l.get(0));
                                l.remove(0);
                        }
                        else {
                                result.add(r.get(0));
                                r.remove(0);
                        }
                }
                while (l.size() > 0) {
                        result.add(l.get(0));
                        l.remove(0);
                }
                while (r.size() > 0) {
                        result.add(r.get(0));
                        r.remove(0);
                }
                return result;
        }
        //Main
        public static void main(String ... $){
                out.println(mergeSort(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("G", "P",
                                                        "A", "A", "O"))));
        }
}
```

## Output:

```
$ javac MergeSort.java  && java MergeSort
[A, A, G, O, P]
```

Comment: I changed it thank you. But when I run there is an overflow error like this: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
 at test/test.SortTextFile.mergeSort(SortTextFile.java:99)                                                
  left = mergeSort(left);

Comment: @서비로브자보키르 it shouldn't! could you please show us what is the input?

Comment: Dev Parzival thank you! It sorting a little bit slowly, maybe I chose unproper algorithm. Anyway I think it worked